What ever happened to Perl?
Think of the most currently "awesome", popular programming language that everyone wants to learn, and is going to "take over the world"...   From the late 1990's to early 2000's this was Perl (note: author's perspective).
At the time it seemed that everything was being written in Perl, and the set of useful functions and modules grew daily.  It was being used everywhere (note: author's perspective).
But now-days, one rarely sees it.
Are there key milestones / missed opportunities that led to Perl becoming less relevant?

Perl 5 to Perl 6 was a much bigger mess than Python 2 to Python 3. Some of the things lots of people disliked in Perl were not there in Python so most people went from Perl to Python 2. Some went to Ruby. I went to NodeJS because all the others couldn't do UTF-8 on the Windows console properly at the time and some of them were messy wrt 64-bit integers. On Perl it was a compile-time switch that made it hard to write code that could use 64-bit ints on both 32-bit and 64-bit builds. Using heterogeneous types with nested structs and arrays is horrible.

Didn't it just get renamed Raku?

@Chenmunka if you mean 'simply' then no, that was part of the mess, if you mean 'recently', then yes (-:

@hippietrail both actually.

The decision to start Perl 6 was (shockingly) 24 years ago. The rename to Raku was 5 years ago. So yeah 19 years of mess before they decided it was going to be too different to Perl 5 to keep the Perl name. So very much not 'merely'. 5 years ago is probably not recently either, so maybe it's 'no' and 'no' (-:

Perl was framed as script language that grew into real' usage, a blemish Python didn't carry. At the same time, Python was a small newcomer, easy to learn when Perl was feature rich and came loaded with tons of modules many for the same purpose, making it hard for beginners to see what' the way to go is. Also, I would't know much bare bone hardware programmable in Perl. So in the end, Perl is os-shell code maxed out, while Python is as minimalist (anf portable) to today's systems as BASIC was in 1970..1990 time frame.

Voted to close as opinion based. While this question is a real interesting one to contemplate, it doesn't have a single/majority answer, but as many different answers as there were people leaving perl development and people picking up Python (groups wich may or may not be conjunct).

I think this is a valid question for retrocomputing.  Retrocomputing doesn't mean that the system in question is totally dead and gone, just that it is of age, is of less use, and we are curious about their history, how they worked, and why things came and went.   The answers that have already been posted are valuable.

My overly simple answer is that Perl fell into a hole between C and Python.  I thought that Perl was better than C, but I also found that Python was much better than Perl.  As a result, I haven't touched Perl in about 15 years, but I still use C and Python to this day.

Perl is the perfect example of a language with too small a standard runtime library.  You can build bike sheds - lots of them - but not skyscrapers with a weak foundation.

Perl jumped the shark when it was forced to be 'object oriented'.  Perl 4 was fine.  Perl 5, why bother?

@Smith To be fair, he didn't close it as 'not retro', he closed it as 'opinion based'. IMHO it's neither. Rather than everyone having a different opinion on the reason Perl faded, everyone pretty much agrees it was a mix of a bunch of reasons.

What happened to Perl? Everybody knew it was a bit shit (a write only language) and the Python happened with almost all of the same advantages and only a few shortcomings.

The simple answer seems to be: Python happened.

I agree this can be answered mostly objectively

Dear me. Let's hope Tom Christiansen doesn't see this question and the comments.

Perl had a significant legacy as a web and scripting language for novices, and it got a few big projects. But, not even at the time, was it seen as a likely replacement for C++ and other "hard" compiled languages.
What Perl missed was that the definition of what comprises a "cheap and easy language" changed from "one you can easily write your first program in" to "one where it's easy to swap out developers and take over codebases".
Perl's slogan of "There's more than one way to do it" is anathema to large codebase maintainability. The modern software engineering philosophy is to reduce variance, make code predictable, readable, and as independent of the developer as possible. A key step was inversion of control, implemented by modern frameworks.
With large codebases, the code must be searchable by automated tools. You want to be able to easily find all your REST controllers, and @RestController is easier to find than a manual implementation. Time pressure leads to comments being omitted, so a one-to-one link between form and function is preferable for large-scale development.
Current hit languages such as Python have started out trying to replicate natural human language. Harder ones like Java get enhanced with frameworks and annotation-based generators like Lombok, which ultimately try to do the same.
With the rise of IDEs and autocompletes, the brevity offered by Perl is losing relevance outside of code golf. Readability and descriptiveness, on the other hand, make a language easier for LLMs to analyze and write.
C++ and Rust thrive in their niche by being high-performance languages, and C# and Javascript are also repositioning themselves as such with the right frameworks. Perl has a performance of only 2.1% that of Rust on equal hardware. In comparison, C# and Java are in the 25%-70% range and even Python can reach 12%. Perl also isn't the easiest language to learn, unless you already know Unix bash.
However, Perl definitely isn't dead. It's a very powerful language for Linux scripting, it's built in, is easy to transition to from bash, so now it's just shrinking back to its original shell scripting and CGI integration role.

Perl really has a sweet spot with FastCGI.

I'll add that that "shrinking back to it's orginal scripting and CGI role" is a bit stronger than the wording makes it sound: Perl used to be the Debian (and consequently, a majority of the Linux) packaging and administrative scripting. These times are gone. Yes, CGI (and fastCGI) web applications do still exist. But they're mostly legacy things; from the top of my head, the only large-scale extant Perl web applications these days are Bugzilla and cPanel. And that's for a good reason: CGI just isn't a very good interface from the application developers point of view, you need something

atop of that to actually write an application that is more than "your feedback has been received and forwareded". And here's where Therac's answer especially shines: where Ruby, Python and others quickly brought forward very feasible, conventions-backed-by-language-based frameworks, Perl basically cultivated "everyone write their own dispatcher for calling a function based on the URL accessed via HTTP", and Catalyst came too late to save the situation. That's the inversion of control mentioned there: perl was, in its approach to things, a report language; it's not a thing to the language

that the program you're building (and that is clearly not a library for other programs to use) has different possible entry points, and it shows through as a tendency of old-style Perl programs to have more global state than they should, for example. Not great for a server application! Can you write beautiful Perl today? Sure! I'm fairly certain you can. In fact, the larger your software project gets, the more you'll have to force yourself to do that. That's the same for a all programming languages – not just Perl – but other languages come with syntax, warnings, and a set of guidelines

that encourage you from the beginning to do something you'll be able to understand in a month from now. Perl is kind of the opposite. It can be dense, and sometimes that's desirable, and sometimes it's not, or verbose, and you can't guess as beginner what to do when.

Can it really be a retrocomputing question if it is about my day job? ;)
The Perl language is still going and the language continues to receive updates. There are semver-"minor" version releases approximately yearly. 5.40.0 came out in June 2024, preceded by 5.38.0 in July 2023. Usually the annual releases pack in quite a lot of new functionality and 5.40 is unexpectedly smaller than usual, mainly just stabilising some experimental features (the net effect is that one doesn't need to use experimental in scripts, but also offers a promise that the feature won't go away) and a few bugfixes and minor new features. However, 5.38 was a somewhat more substantial release and I don't think that not having a whole slew of new features in 5.40 means it's stopped development and is on life support. Let's see what 5.42 brings in 2025 before declaring Perl dead.
Common CPAN modules may not receive substantial updates any more. Let's look at something you probably remember from back when Perl was the hot new thing: the (in)famous CGI.pm. It came out way back in 1995, and was probably instrumental in Perl being associated with web development. Parsing CGI and form parameters is a well-defined task that has not changed in the intervening decades. I am surprised it's still getting updates at all. Sometimes stuff is just finished.
Perl 6/Raku was a misstep, and isn't really the Perl we all know and love/hate. Perl 6 started development in 2000(!), was overly ambitious with everybody's pet feature thrown in, seemed to have an endless trail of buggy and slow betas, and finally released in 2015 under a new name to avoid confusion with Perl (5). The most recent release was 2020. It is a classic example of the second-system effect.
As to uses of Perl (5), it's just rather low-profile. A lot of that stuff from the late 1990s and 2000s is still running and requires maintenance and new features from time to time. I mean, I don't see a question "whatever happened to bash/awk/expect/etc?": these are all components of the Unix toolbox which just keep on running without feeling the need to run a continuous marketing campaign and to grow indefinitely. Not everything has to follow capitalist dogma.
When I want a simple Unix tool which somehow doesn't already exist, I'll slap together a prototype in Perl. Often it works well enough that I never get round to rewriting it in Rust, the current sexiness.

Based on what you’ve seen over the years, how large would you expect the user base to be. Just your gut feeling?

No one asks what happened to bash and awk because they're still widely used and new bits of code are being written for them. perl on the other hand has disappeared almost completely

A lot of the popularity came from web programming.  Perl had a sweet spot in being a scripting language that could be executed as a CGI script inside the web server without requiring special admin rights.
This was really something back then as the web was a revolution in how people used the internet.
Perl was too terse so pretty much a write-only language, combined with a lot of legacy side effects and lack of a standard runtime library for web work caused both its bad reputation but also The Big Redesign to Perl 6 which took so long that others like ASP and JSP caught up and overtook.
I still occasionally whip a Perl script together for slicing data out of a text file, but for non-trivial work other languages exist. Pity because I really like there is more than one way to do it.

It is mostly how much easier python is to deal with. A quote I encountered "python is executable pseudo-code, perl is executable line noise".

But this came down to the user.  Even today it's possible to write a C for() loop that does everything without a body.  Or write your entire JavaScript app as anonymous functions.  But I guess needing $_ was kind of asking for it.

You can write line noise in any language.

It's perfectly possible to write legible Perl, it just takes programmer discipline. From distant memory, adding use English; gave you nice descriptive names for all of the punctuation character variables.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - sure, but it's much easier in some languages (e.g., TECO)

Funniest book I ever made the mistake of buying was Object-Oriented Perl - talk about putting lipstick on a pig!  Thank goodness my Perl days as my day job were short-lived: Just one one-month assignment.

@davidbak Meet APL.

I've met APL! And liked it a lot!  My first two programming languages were APL and IBM 1620 assembler, at a Junior College (2 yr community college, as it was known then) near my high school.  Bu in those days we used the real APL notation with an APL\360 typeball for their selectric-based terminals. Nothing wrong with that!  Definitely not line noise!  (YMMV.)

@bodgit It's perfectly possible to write a lot of stuff, maybe even the majority, in legible Perl. But heterogeneous datatypes are a special kind of hell due to the sigils meaning something like the type you're dereferencing. If you've had to use Perl to interoperate with binary formats it is brain-melting. Even if the original coder was good at it doesn't mean it will be 'legible', which really means all Perl coders can read and grok it. The source of ExifTool does the best job of making such things legible in Perl I've ever seen. It may be using new syntax that wasn't there when I left Perl?

It is possible to write legible Perl, but is it probable? I would argue no.
